# Setar valor no excel com base em uma lista drop down

Tags: microsoft-excel

Preciso fazer uma lista drop down no excel no seguinte estilo:

Mercadoria  |   Valor

Na mesma planilha tenho uma tabela com uma relação de mercadorias e seus respectivos valores.

Abaixo do campo mercadoria gostaria que aparecesse uma lista drop down com todas as mercadorias cadastradas na outra tabela e que o campo valor fosse aplicado automaticamente ao selecionar uma mercadoria.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Na célula de mercadoria crie uma validação de dados. Vá para a guia Dados>Validação de Dados, no campo Permitir escolha a opção Lista, irá abrir um novo campo chamado fonte, clique na seta para cima e selecione a sua tabela.

Na célula do valor, faça um Procv. =Procv(Célula da Mercadoria;Selecione sua Tabela;Número da coluna onde está o valor;0)